# Using a decorator with Django blocks the request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-decorators

I'm trying to create my own decorator in order to validate a REST call with Django (using Django Rest Framework).

The decorator looks like this:

```
def allowed_states(allowed=[]):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            print(func)
            result = func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

The request API looks something like this:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(
    operation_id="my_api",
    responses={
        status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT: "",
    }
)
@action(detail=True, methods=["DELETE"])
@allowed_states(allowed=["state1", "state2"])
def my_api(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # do some stuff here
```

When my `@allowed_states` decorator is removed, the call works just fine. When I add it back I get a 404 error from Django framework saying it could not find a url pattern to execute for this call.

I tried removing `self` from `wrapper` (and from the `func` invoke as well).
Also I tried changing the decorators order above the function call.
Both didn't work.

The stack trace doesn't say much, merely that django could not find the url pattern:

```
 Using the URLconf defined in 
                <code>my_project.urls</code>,
      Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
```

(and then the order of url patterns as they appear in `my_project.urls`)

Comment: In case `my_api`is function based view `self` argument is not required. Not sure it's reason of error, but try to remove `self` argument. Can you add full traceback?

Comment: How do you expect the order of function to be called?  Here it will call allowed_states() first and then action(). Try changing the order if your logic differs.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner - I forgot to mention that I already tried it without the `self` param and it doesn't work.

Comment: @yogi - Tried this before I posted the question. Same behavior :/

Comment: @neverwalkaloner - Regarding the stack trace, this is what it says: `Page not found at <my_url>` and the error I just added.

Comment: @Avi can you add your `urls.py` file also?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner - Unfortunately I can't. Not allowed by company regulations :/
What would you hope to see there?

Comment: @Avi probably typo in your urlpattern or something like this.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner - The thing is, it works when I remove the new decorator...

Comment: @neverwalkaloner - What I do see is that the `my_api` function doesn't appear in the paths django searches while the other view functions in the same class do appear in this list.

Comment: If URL routing does automatic registration when using the ``@action`` decorator by working off the name of the handler function, your decorator will not work as it doesn't preserve introspection functionality. You can try using ``functools.wraps`` as is normally done in your decorator implementation and see if it helps. Better still, use a decorator library such as ``wrapt`` which provides more reliable decorators than typical pattern people use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a suggestion in the comments I used `functools.wraps` and that solved the problem:

```
from functools import wraps

def allowed_states(allowed=[]):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            print(func)
            result = func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```